# Error : Missing or corrupt GameMaker build tools - 0x4F030002 when building

Tags: game-maker, game-maker-studio-2

Recently I've updated to GameMaker 2 v2022.5.1.16. When I'm building a project now, I get `Error : Missing or corrupt GameMaker build tools - 0x4F030002` compile error. Is there a way to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Go to `Preferences > Runtime Feeds > Master` and choose the later version